# VBA Number formatting not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with number formatting in my code.

If I stop the macro at this subroutine and run it step by step (F8) it works fine, no issues. However, if it's run as a whole with the rest of the macro (won't post the whole thing as it's quite huge) it just doesn't apply the number formatting and I can't seem to figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
Private Sub VolumeIncluded(TWs As Worksheet, MWs2 As Worksheet, MLngth As Double, MFinal As String, TLnght As Double, TFinal As String)

Dim TFtLnght As Double

On Error GoTo NextSheet

TLnght = TWs.Range("$A$" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row
TFinal = "$A$" & TLnght
TWs.Range(TFinal) = "Volume Included"
With TWs.Range(TFinal)
    .Interior.Color = 12611584
    .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

MLngth = MWs2.Range("$H$" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MFinal = "$A$16:$H" & MLngth
MWs2.Range(MFinal).Copy

TLnght = TWs.Range("$A$" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
TFinal = "$A$" & TLnght
TFormat = "$H$" & TLnght
TWs.Range(TFinal).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'----------This piece doesn't work-----------
TFtLnght = TWs.Range("$H$" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
TFinal = "$H$" & TLnght & ":" & "$H$" & TFtLnght
Range(TFinal).NumberFormat = "#,##0"

NextSheet:
End Sub
```

Comment: If it applies when you only run this piece of code then the error is probably in the other part of the code. Have you run through all the code with F8 to check that you arent overwriting your formatting somewhere?

Comment: @UGP Yes, I've just run the whole code with F8 and it worked as intended, formatting was applied and it didn't error out at any point. However, if I run the whole thing at once it doesn't apply the formatting. Everything else works the same as if running it step by step. Driving me crazy...

Comment: Have you tried `TWs.Range(TFinal).NumberFormat = "#,##0"`

Comment: @darcyq Sure enough, that was the issue. I can't believe I didn't see it...feeling stupid now haha. Thanks a lot, finally works as intended.

Comment: @Mazura_ No worries, i'm glad it helps. Pls accept mine as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TWs.Range(TFinal).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

When you call Range() it's always safe to reference from a worksheet object that you know, since the active worksheet is used by default.